# Why did Walt change his mind about Jesse "handling" the stolen drug money?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In the *Breaking Bad* episode "Breakage" (S02E05) one of *Jesse*'s dealers gets robbed by some junkies. When *Walt* comes to know this, he gives *Jesse* a gun and urges him to *"handle it"* in order for them not to lose their respect on the streets (which then leads to *Jesse*'s unpleasant experiences with a junkie family and an ATM). But at the beginning of "Negro y Azul" (S02E07) *Walt* suddenly changes his mind and after not having reached *Jesse* for quite some time just leaves him a message saying

> Oh and by the way, that thing we talked about, when I said "handle it". Well, don't, just let it go.

But **why did he suddenly change his mind about this matter?** Was he simply feeling a bit of remorse, not being the hardened gangster yet (though, he was quite determined when he persuaded *Jesse* to handle it), or is there more to it? Or does it have something to do with the stupid-ass student he justed talked to right before making this call (maybe he didn't have confidence in *Jesse* anymore and thought he'd screw it up)?

Comment: Walt and Jesse have complicated relationship but still they have kind of father-son  relationship and walt somewhere care about him, That made the change of heart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My Personal Interpretation:

**Walt cares for Jesse**

Walt cares for Jesse, I mean, in the previous episodes when Tuco beats Jesse badly, Walt gets so worked up and goes to Tuco with full rage and destroys the place and  gets the money (may be he wouldn't have gone to a place full of gangsters if it's just for the money especially a guy who cares about his family so much) and another time when Tuco was trying to Kill Jesse on the couch in an isolated house with Don Salamanca, Walt tries real hard to convince Tuco that he needs Jesse. In the further episodes, especially in "ABQ" S02E13 you'll understand that Walt stays with Jesse in tough times and acts as a fatherly figure.

**Walt needs Jesse**

Walt wants to make more money and the only key for it is Jesse, he's a drug dealer and he can make money for Walt by selling Meth and he is the only guy Walt trusts.

May be because of the above reasons, Walt doesn't want Jesse to be hurt and I think Walt was genuinely concerned about Jesse while saying

> Oh and by the way, that thing we talked about, when I said "handle it". Well, don't, just let it go.

because he thinks Jesse might get hurt.

Comment: Makes sense indeed. I probably just didn't consider that *Jesse* might get in serious danger (well, he did, but I wouldn't have thought that's what comes to *Walt*'s mind). But if you put it that way, it makes quite some sense.

Comment: @ Napoleon Wilson I too don't know what's on Walt's mind, it's only my guess. And I don't think Walt suddenly changed his mind, when Walt finds out that Skinny pete is robbed, he was angry with Jesse ('cause Jesse always finds a way to disappoint Walt with his dumb actions) and tells him to handle the gun. And Walt goes to his home and around midnight (I think) he calls Jesse and tells him to let it go. I think Walt had enough time to think and realize that making Jesse to use the gun would put Jesse in danger.

Answer (score 3):

Walt is aware of the possibility that Jesse decides to disobey him, given what he already knows about Jesse's personality and their complex relationship.

Therefore, when Walt pulls out his order, he is using what is called "reverse psychology". He really aims to get Jesse to do it.

Comment: Now that is also an interesting idea. I'm not sure I buy that entirely from how the scene played out, but it's definitely an interesting approach.